# WPF in-memory image not rendering after assigned to Image.Source

Tags: c#, wpf, image, render

I've been searching for hours to find what's the problem and can't find it. I'm using this function to convert a base64String to a BitmapImage

```
public static BitmapImage Base64StringToBitmapImage(string base64String) {
        byte[] byteBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteBuffer);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

        using (memoryStream) {
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = memoryStream;
            bitmapImage.EndInit();

            bitmapImage.Freeze();
        }
        memoryStream.Close();
        memoryStream = null;
        byteBuffer = null;

        return bitmapImage;
    }
```

And then assign it to a property of my ViewModel that is bound to a  view:

```
ProcessImage = Base64StringToBitmapImage(_imageString);
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Image x:Name="PART_IMAGE" Width="auto" Height="auto" Source="{Binding ProcessImage}" />
```

I've done some test by setting the image background to red and I've noticed the image get resized as it should (1920x1080 since its a printscreen from my computer), but I can't see the rendered image... I've done many tests and searched all over Google and haven't found any solutions... Anyone sees something wrong with this code or have an idea what's causing the problem? I'm really running out of options :(

Comment: Are you sure the `BitmapImage` is correct? Did you try to save it to a file for instance for testing?

Comment: Tried it just now. It does seems like there's no image as the jpeg created is only a  gray screen.. Tough when I inspect the the bitmap properties trough the debugger, everything seems OK. I'm receiving the image string from a remote server. I've compared both string from client/server and they're exactly the same.

Comment: I've found the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Should this be closed? There wasn't problem at all, in the end...

Comment: Yes, the question should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. After saving the image on the server side, I've discovered the printscreen image wasn't correct. I did a few modification and everything worked fine.